# When Router-Link jumps the same name, it will not refresh the page

Tags: vuejs3

First, my routing function is like this：

```js
const routes = [
    ...
    {
        path: '/article/:id/',
        name:'ArticleDetail',
        component: ArticleDetail,
    },]
```

Second I sent a request to the background and obtained certain data. The request function is like this. There is no problem with this process and the information obtained is correct.

```js
onMounted(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('/api/article/latest_articles/');
    latestTitle.value = response.data
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})
```

Third, I wrote the display content in the template, and the content of this display is correct.
This piece is also displayed in the form of components.

```html
<div v-for="article in latestTitle" :key="article.id" class="article-item">
      <router-link :to="{ name:'ArticleDetail', params:{id:article.id}}" class="router-link">
        {{ article.title }}
      </router-link>
</div>
```

When I'm ready, I click on one of the article links and I'll jump to the area named: 'ArticleDetail' along the route. At the same time, I'll get the desired article and display it.

Next, when I clicked on another article link, only the URL address changed, but the overall page did not change.

Comment: Please provide the code of ArticleDetail component so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because vue only renders the same component once, and doesn't go any further than that for the rest of the rents in the entire lifecycle if it doesn't listen further.

So in the script module I added the corresponding listening step to get the data again if the url has changed

```
export default {
    name:'ArticleDetial',
    ...
    watch: {
    $route: function (to, from) {
      if (to !== from) {
        this.fetchArticleTitle(to.params.id); # Assuming this is the function that fetches the data to the backend
      }
    }
  },
}
```